# App crashes when I use SimpleDateFormat class with "YYYY"

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am using SimpleDateFormat class to get current year like this

```
SimpleDateFormat currentYear = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
Date thisYear = new Date();
String stringThisYear  = currentYear .format(thisYear );
```

It is working fine in here(India) ,but it crashed when it run on Malaysia by other people.After lot of debugging and searching ,i found that it is happening due to no mention of locale.So I changed my code to this

```
SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Still it is crashing, so I use calendar instance to get current year like this

```
 int thisYear=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

But i want to know what is issue with simpleDateFormat as most of my code is already has simpleDateFormat class.So I want to know the reason for crash,if anyone has solution,Please help me.Thank you

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: As I already mentioned , I am from India ,so when I am testing my app here ,it is working fine but when It is running on Malaysia ,it is crashing. Now your have question like this"How you know it is due to simpleDateFormat ?",I did someb test and use predefined value of string for taking current year and told my friend to test it on there again,that time it was working fine.

Comment: you should use for sure crashlytics before pushing your app into the store, it will notify you about where the users are crashing and all the stuff you need in order to get errors that you wont have on runtime in your debug

Comment: Ok thanks ,on next update ,I will sure do that but for now do have any solution for this?

Comment: Just change your language and locale,timezone,time to Malaysia in your device and debug.You will get the solution.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Then use `Year.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")).toString()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you must use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY"

On old versions of Android, using "YYYY" makes your app to crash. Nothing to do with the country/Locale

"Y" stands for week year and not year, as specified [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**EDIT 2**

More [information here](https://www.juandebravo.com/2015/04/10/java-yyyy-date-format)

> yyyy is the pattern string to identify the year in the
>   SimpleDateFormat class.
>
> Java 7 introduced YYYY as a new date pattern to identify the date week
>   year.
>
> An average year is exactly 52.1775 weeks long, which means that
>   eventually a year might have either 52 or 53 weeks considering
>   indivisible weeks.
>
> Using YYYY unintendedly while formatting a date can cause severe
>   issues in your Java application.

As mentioned by @OleV.V., the format `Y` is only supported on Android API 24+. Using any versions below API 24 makes the app to crash.

Comment: Thanks mate for your solution. But then why though it is working fine in India while not working for Malaysia. Any idea?

Comment: As I said, the new versions of Android support "YYYY" when the old ones not. So probably you have a recent version for testing so it seems to work, but your customer has an old one so it crashes. I forgot since which version this is supported, but try with the lowest version your app supports, on an emulator, and you should be able to reproduce the error

Comment: This answer is supported by [the API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat): `Y` is for Week year and is supported on API levels 24+.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the link. So yeah, using "Y" on API below 24 makes the app to crash as not supported. But even so, you can end with unexpected result using this feature unintentionally (as described in the link of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default locale for the device like this

```
SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue using this it's working fine.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY",Locale.US);
```